# Winrt / XAML / C++ : Get Color from String Value

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm current writing some `WinRT` components in C++, and I need to work out how to take a Color string (eg "#FF448DCA" ) and convert it to a `Color` for use constructing a `SolidColorBrush`.

In `WPF` we had the `BrushConverter`, but we dont seem to have an equivalent in `WinRT`

I can do it in `C#` by splitting strings, and converting to Hexadecimal chunks etc etc.., but thats beyond my current `C++` skills.

Does anyone have a quick answer before I spend loads of time trying to work it out (my C++ would improve, but my dealdlines will suffer)

Thanks

Comment: I guess, you can try the dedicated MSDN Forum, such as "Building Metro style apps with C++" -http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a short example how this can be done using regexps, written with vs 2010 express. This is just parsing, later use ColorHelper as Marc have written

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

bool GetARGBFromS(const std::string& s, int& a, int& r, int& g, int& b) {   
    try {
        std::smatch m;
        if ( regex_search(s, m, std::regex("#([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})")) ) {
            a = std::stoi(m[1].str(), 0, 16);
            r = std::stoi(m[2].str(), 0, 16);
            g = std::stoi(m[3].str(), 0, 16);
            b = std::stoi(m[4].str(), 0, 16);
        }   
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch(...){ /*should catch/report specific exceptions, but thats just example*/ return false; }
    return true;
}

int main() {

    int a,r,g,b;
    if ( GetARGBFromS("#FF448DCA", a, r, g, b) )
    {}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just because we can use regular expressions doesn't mean we should... how about the simpler/faster/easier `return std::swscanf(s.c_str(), L"#%2x%2x%2x%2x", &a, &r, &g, &b) == 4;`?  (`GetARGBFromS` could be modified to take a `wchar_t const*` as well, since we don't really need a `std::string` here.)

Comment: Wow, that gives me exaclt ywhat I want, thanks. Im going to modify it to return a SolidColorBrush from the resolved Color (using ColorHelper). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you'll need to convert it to discrete byte values.

Once you have those you use the ColorHelper class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh747822.aspx) to convert them into a Color structure (there isn't a Color.FromArgb method in C++).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it.

```
        public static Brush ColorToBrush(string color)
    {
        color = color.Replace("#", "");
        if (color.Length == 6)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper.FromArgb(255,
                byte.Parse(color.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                byte.Parse(color.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                byte.Parse(color.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Call by

```
textbox1.BorderBrush = ColorToBrush("#ffff00");
```